# Extremely low accuracy for IRIS dataset using CNN

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, conv-neural-network

Being a beginner, I am trying to implement my CNN on IRIS dataset with only 2 labels considered:

- Iris-setosa: 0
- Iris-versicolor: 1

I am using 90% data for training and 10% for testing with 1D CNN and Adam optimization and learning rate of 0.001. The accuracy achieved is around 40-50% which also is changing with every execution. Please suggest what should be done.

DATA LOADING TO DATALOADERS:

```
#Training data
class IrisDataset(T.utils.data.Dataset):

  def __init__(self, Iris):    
    sc = StandardScaler()    
    X_tr = sc.fit_transform(trainX)
    Y_tr = trainY     
    self.X_tr = torch.tensor(X_tr, dtype = torch.float32)
    self.Y_tr = torch.tensor(Y_tr, dtype = torch.float32)

  def __len__(self):
    return len(self.Y_tr)

  def __getitem__(self, idx):        
    return self.X_tr[idx], self.Y_tr[idx]

train_ds = IrisDataset(Iris)

bat_size = 1
# Leaving only labels 0 and 1 
idx = np.append(np.where(train_ds.Y_tr == 0)[0], 
                np.where(train_ds.Y_tr == 1)[0])
train_ds.X_tr = train_ds.X_tr[idx]
train_ds.Y_tr = train_ds.Y_tr[idx]

#len(train_ds)
train_ldr = T.utils.data.DataLoader(train_ds,
    batch_size=bat_size, shuffle=True)
batch = next(iter(train_ldr))

# and in the same way test data
```

```
#NETWORK CLASS

class Net(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Net, self).__init__()
        self.conv1 = nn.Conv1d(1, 6, kernel_size=1)
        self.conv2 = nn.Conv1d(6, 16, kernel_size=1)
        self.dropout = nn.Dropout2d()
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(64, 16)
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(16, 1)

    def forward(self, x):
        x = F.relu(self.conv1(x))
        x = F.relu(self.conv2(x))
        x = self.dropout(x)
        x = x.view(x.size(0), -1)
        x = F.relu(self.fc1(x))
        x = self.fc2(x)
        return T.cat((x, 1 - x), -1)
```

```
# MODEL TRAINING 
model = Net()
optimizer = optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=0.001)
loss_func = nn.NLLLoss()
epochs = 2
loss_list = []

model.train()

for epoch in range(epochs):
    total_loss = []
    
    for X_tr, Y_tr in train_ldr:
       X_tr = X_tr.unsqueeze(0)
       optimizer.zero_grad()
 
       output = model(X_tr)
       pred = output.argmax(dim=1, keepdim=True)
       Y_tr = torch.tensor(Y_tr, dtype=torch.long)
       loss = loss_func(output, Y_tr.squeeze(1))
        # Backward pass
       loss.backward()
        # Optimize the weights
       optimizer.step()
        
       total_loss.append(loss.item())

    loss_list.append(sum(total_loss)/len(total_loss))
    print('Training [{:.0f}%]\tLoss: {:.4f}'.format(
         100. * (epoch + 1) / epochs, loss_list[-1]))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The mistake is here

```
def forward(self, x):
   x = F.relu(self.conv1(x))
   .
   .
   x = self.fc2(x)
   return T.cat((x, 1 - x), -1)
'''
The thing is that the output from the dense layer is not the probability and hence
you subtracting it form 1 also don't make any sense. It will become probability if 
you use sigmoid activation after it.
'''
def forward(self, x):
   x = F.relu(self.conv1(x))
   .
   .
   x = self.fc2(x) 
   x = torch.nn.functional.sigmoid(x)
   return T.cat((x, 1 - x), -1)
```

But I would recommend that you change your loss function to BCE as below. This is less prone to error and is same as above in terms of results. Also you can read [docs](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.NLLLoss.html) for NLL and see that it says "Obtaining log-probabilities in a neural network is easily achieved by adding a LogSoftmax layer in the last layer of your network. You may use CrossEntropyLoss instead, if you prefer not to add an extra layer." So you can either add `LogSoftmax` or use `CrossEntropy`.

```
# LogSoftmax
def forward(self, x):
   x = F.relu(self.conv1(x))
   .
   .
   x = self.fc2(x) 
   x = torch.nn.functional.log_softmax(x, dim=1)
   return x

loss_func = nn.NLLLoss()


# BCE
def forward(self, x):
   x = F.relu(self.conv1(x))
   .
   .
   x = self.fc2(x) 
   return x

loss_func = torch.nn.BCEWithLogitsLoss()
```

Comment: The rectified mistake of (x) and BCEWithLogitsLoss has improved the accuracy. Thank you so much.

Comment: The above error is gone but when I tried to compare and print both the (Label, predicted_label),  all the predicted labels are 0 and the model is not predicting any of the label as 1, both in training and testing data. Please suggest me where could be the error in training the model on IRIS dataset.

Comment: Share your code. If possible then share the colab link.

Comment: Link: https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1OSSGv0p_u8ndxD8_NTSSJT77GcvqU8Ma?usp=sharing. I have taken only 1st 100 samples of IRIS dataset with first 50(label 0) and last 50(label 1) converted manually in my dataset file. Thanks for help in advance.

Comment: I have shared the link for the code. If possible, please let me know where the mistake is.